# I can't write regex to transform topic names for debezium connector

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to set up debezium to be able to rename topics. My tables have the same type prefix dbo.tRB_ODPP_TableName. Topics should have titles without a prefix, i.e. just TableName. Can't figure out how to write regex.

I use debezium config params:

```
"transforms": "dropTopicPrefix",
"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex": "^[^.]+.(.*)",
"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement": "$1"
```

SOLVED

right regex was - ^([a-zA-Z]+.)+(.*)

Comment: Have you tried `"dbo\\.tRB_ODPP_([a-zA-Z]+)"`?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help =(

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're starting with and what you want the end result to look like? I'm a little unclear on what is being asked here.

Comment: I have a few tables in SQL Server db. They all have the same prefix - dbo.tRB_ODPP_ So I want that debezium will be able to remove that prefix in kafka topic name.

Comment: solved - "transforms": "dropPrefix",
"transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "^([a-zA-Z]+.)+(.*)",
"transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "$1"

Comment: Please answer your post below rather than use the comments